# Did Assad use chemical weapons in Syria?

Tags: war, weapons, syria

Related to [Were chemical weapons being used in the civil war in Syria before 2014?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16104/are-chemical-weapons-being-used-in-the-civil-war-in-syria).

While the consensus at the time seemed to be that the government was using chemical weapons (this in particular was the position of the US government), and that there was reasonable grounds for assuming that chemical weapons had been used, there seems to be increasing popular dissent with this view. However, it is unclear to me whether this popular dissent is just an internet factoid, or something based upon solid evidence that has since emerged. With the benefit of hindsight, does it now seem likely or unlikely that the government of Syria specifically used chemical weapons on civilians? This is separate from whether chemical weapons have been used *at all* during the course in the civil war.

Comment: US government position ≠ international consensus.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: @Sklivvz not really. The other question is out of date, nor does it ask specifically about Assad which was a causa bellum for supporters of the rebels. I really would like an answer to the question in all honesty. The answer to the other question pretty much says "the jury's out" which doesn't really cut it at this stage.

Comment: @Stumbler if you feel the other question needs a better answer offer a bounty on that. Do not repost the same question. I'm closing this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Sklivvz "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. *If those answers do not fully address your question*, **please ask a new question.**" ?

Comment: @Stumbler that means "if your question is actually a different one, ask it separately", but your question is not really different at all.