# Did the Syrian government use chemical weapons in Khan Shaykhun?

Tags: politics, war, syria

Since April 4th 2017, reports have been released about a [chemical attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Khan_Shaykhun_chemical_attack) that is supposed to have occurred in a Syrian town called Khan Shaykhun.

[According to the BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-39500319), "[t]he UK's foreign secretary, a rebel commander and a weapons expert all said evidence pointed to an attack by the Syrian government".

- Were chemical weapons used in Khan Shaykhun on April 4th?
- Did the Syrian government order the use of chemical weapons in Khan Shaykhun on that day?
- If so, were these chemical weapons deployed from aircrafts of the Syrian government's forces?
- Did Bashar al-Assad order the use of chemical weapons on Khan Shaykhun?

Comment: That wikipedia article has a number of sources, surely one is as  acceptable as any that is likely to ever address the issue.

Comment: This is a good question, but it's premature, and thus, unanswerable for now.

Comment: Also, very related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16104/are-chemical-weapons-being-used-in-the-civil-war-in-syria

Comment: Follow [Bellingcat](https://www.bellingcat.com/), they keep updating their detective work

Comment: Video of the attack: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1M6LXFAJ1Rw

Comment: Another video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=32&v=Om-buItaNNs